# Norton Enterprise Won't Uninstall?

Tags: anti-virus, uninstall

I'm trying to uninstall Norton Enterprise on Windows 7. I ran the Norton uninstaller (the full uninstall), but it's interfering with my Kaspersky 6.0 installation. I've rebooted, but it's still listed in the add/remove programs. How can I uninstall Norton Enterprise?

Comment: Success! Thanks so much! I used the Norton Removal Tool in safe mode, and had no errors when installing Kaspersky.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you said you used the Norton uninstaller, are you talking about the one that came with the product?

If that is so, I recommend you download the [Norton Removal Tool](ftp://ftp.symantec.com/public/english_us_canada/removal_tools/Norton_Removal_Tool.exe), then go in to Safe Mode as Tom Wijsman suggested (Press <kbd>F8</kbd> a few times as soon as your computer turns on and before you see the Windows Flag.), then run this tool.

Hopefully it will remove every last shred of Norton from your system and allow you to install Kaspersky.

However, that being said, I just did a quick look around, and version 6 looks to be the version from 2007, they are on version 11 now. I doubt 6 will still be compatible with Windows 7. This may be the issue as to why you can't install it, rather than Norton interfering with it. (Unless you can give a screenshot/or exact error message?).

All this being said, I would highly recommend you take a look at [Microsoft Security Essentials](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/security_essentials/default.aspx), which will give you  **free**, up to date and good antivirus.

Comment: I'm doing tech support for my college, and they're using Kaspersky--it's been working pretty well with our Windows machines (including 7), but I don't really have any control over the software I'm trying to install. I just have to get it done.

Comment: @Christine: Good luck! And welcome to Super User...

Comment: No problem, I understand.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Comment: Could you give me a little more detail on that one? If I use safe mode, will I be ok to install Kaspersky? Sorry, not really a PC person.

Comment: @Christine: Click on the image, it explains it in detail. By running safe mode, your anti virus won't be loaded which makes it easier to uninstall and install virus scanners without them locking files. If it doesn't work in safe mode, report back to us... :)

Comment: @Christine: Sorry, couldn't resist this picture. But seems highly inappropriate now that I have seen your profile. I was rather expecting a different type of person to say "why didn't I thought of this; thanks, that will do". It's kinda late here... :(

Comment: Haha, thanks! Not a problem at all. You're completely right--most people would be fine with a safe mode screen.